# Automatically enable a mode with dir-locals.el

Tags: minor-mode, directory-local-variables

I'm trying to achieve the effect of automatically calling `M-x importmagic-mode` whenever I open a python file, but I need to do this in a directory specific way, using `dir-locals.el`.

I have this in `dir-locals.el`:

```
((python-mode . (
                 (eval . (importmagic-mode 1))
)))
```

But I still have to `M-x importmagic-mode` every time I open a python file. What am I missing to make this automatic?  Is my syntax just wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the 1.

```
                 (eval . (importmagic-mode))
```

via this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63797942/1052117